# Should I remove the commas?

Tags: commas, run-on-sentences

> If you find no time for politeness and for checking that the guests are comfortable, **because of your remaining  busy with the schedule**, I shall give you less than what I give to those who are hospitable.

I believe that the commas are correctly placed, but it makes it sound as if the words between the commas are not necessary and can be removed. But that’s not the case. They are essential for the correct meaning. So do I remove the commas or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the first comma. "Because" is a conjunction and so you do not strictly need to put a comma at this point in the sentence.

It goes without saying that moving, removing or adding commas will change the flow of your sentence and possibly the meaning so what precisely should be done is up to you and the precise meaning you want to convey.

Answer (score 0):

You do need the comma before "because" precisely because "because" is a conjunction and without the comma the sentence says that "the guests are comfortable because of your remaining busy with the schedule". In other words that it is because of your remaining busy with the schedule that the guests are comfortable, which is not what you are saying.

The "because" actually refers to "If you find no time", so the comma sets off the entire clause that begins with "If you find no time" and binds "because" to that clause rather than to the comfort of the guests.